# How do I enter multiple answers for a single command so that they are output randomly? (Discord)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This line of code generates output using a user-written message command:

```
robot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content == "%ex") {
        message.reply("Random message");
    } 
});
```

But I want one of 3 messages at random, for example, `"Hello!"`, but I do not know how to implement it better.

Comment: The first thing I would do is fix your grouping.  You need to end the `if` parenthesis right after the condition.  Secondly, you can try making an array of random messages and then picking one using `Math.random()` and the easy `min, max` equation: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min`.  Try posting back here after you have done that if you can't get it working.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/7uk0wg/how_to_program_bot_with_multiple_responses_to_one/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work on your code formatting :) Not sure if I've understood correctly but this will send back a random message as a response

```
function randomMessage(){
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*2); // 0, 1 or 2
    switch(randomNumber){
        case 0: return 'Hello!';
        case 1: return 'Bye!';
        case 2: return 'Random';
    }
}

robot.on('message', (message)=>{ 
    if(message.content == "%ex"){
        message.reply(randomMessage());
    }
});
```